# Unable to submit custom field, which extends dataview

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2122) which demonstrates this strange behaviour. In a nutshell, I have a custom field which extends `Ext.DataView`. I need to extend dataview, because this field is supposed to have dynamic contents. This is how my field is defined:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.SimpleList', {
    extend: 'Ext.DataView',
    alias: 'widget.simplelist', 
    requires: [
        'Ext.XTemplate'
    ],
    itemSelector: 'div.record',
    isFormField: true,
    getFieldIdentifier: function () {
        return this.name;
    },
    getModelData: function() {
        var me = this;
        var data = {};
        data[me.getFieldIdentifier()] = me.getValue();
        return data;
    },
    getSubmitData: function() { return {}; },
    submitValue: true,
    isValid: function () { return true; },
    isDirty: function () { return true; },
    validate: function () { return true; },
    isFileUpload: function() { return false; }, 
    constructor: function(config) {
        Ext.applyIf(config, {
            tpl: [
               '{% var name = this.owner.name; %}',
                '<tpl for=".">',
                    '<div class="record"><input record-id="{id}" type="checkbox" name="{[name]}" /> {label}</div>',
                '</tpl>',
                {compiled: true}
            ]
        });
        this.callParent([config]);
    },
    getValue: function () {        
        var cb = this.el.select("input").elements, i, res = [];
        for (i in cb) {
            if (cb.hasOwnProperty(i) && cb[i].checked) {
                res.push(cb[i].getAttribute("record-id"));
            }
        }
        return res;
    },
    setValue: function (values) {
        //not yet implemented
    }
});
```

And this is how I add this field to a form:

```
Ext.create("Ext.form.Panel",{
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items:[{
        xtype: "textfield",
        name: "text"
    },{
       xtype: "simplelist",
       name: "list",
       store: {
            fields: ["id", "label", "checked"],
            data: [{"id": "1", "label": "One"},{"id": "2", "label": "Two"}]
        }
    },{
       xtype: "button",
       text: "Submit",
       handler: function () {
            var frm = this.up("form").getForm();
            console.log(frm.getFieldValues()); // it' ok
            //simplelist field is not submitted
            this.up("form").getForm().submit({
                url: "/"
            });
        }
   }]
});
```

As you can see, when I submit the form I log to the console form field values. And what is interesting about that, is that I see my custom field among those field values. So, I have a field with `isFormField` set to `true`, this field is in the list returned by form `getFields()` method and this field is also among those values returned by form `getFieldValues()` method, but still this field is not submitted. What is wrong with that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code uses `basicForm.getFieldValues()`, which calls `basicForm.getValues()` with some parameters, while the form while submitting uses the same method with different parameters. One of those parameters is `useDataValues`, which decides whether to use the `getModelData` or `getSubmitData`.

You are returning empty object in your `getSubmitData` method, which prevents it to correctly get the values.

All you need to change, for both methods to work in your current state, is this:

```
getSubmitData: function() {
    return this.getModelData();
}
```

Comment: In spirit of 'teach a man how to fish', don't be afraid to dig in (any) framework code to find out, how it works and what you can do to make it work for you. All I did was putting a breakpoint in `Ext.form.Basic.submit()` method and seeing where it leads me. Also, some side advice, you can avoid calling the `.getForm()` part, because `formpanel` also has submit mehtod, and all it does is call the `basicForm` submit method.

Comment: I really appreciate your advice! Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome. The fiddle was very helpful. Also I slightly edited my answer, to better explain, what is happening in the background.